# Determining convergence or divergence of series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{ n+\sin (n)} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am wondering the **convergence or divergence** following series

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 
\frac{(-1)^n}{ n+\sin (n)}
\\
$$

My 1st attempt is 'alternating series test'

$$
$$

But, $$\frac{1}{n+\sin(n)}$$

isn't monotone decreasing. SO I failed...

$$
$$

Please give me some advice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{(-1)^n}{n+\sin n}&=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+\Bigl(\frac{(-1)^n}{n+\sin n}-\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\Bigr)\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}-\frac{(-1)^n\sin n}{(n+\sin n)n}.
\end{align*}

- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges conditionally.
- $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\sin n}{(n+\sin n)n}$ converges absolutely.

Comment: the last series "converges absolutely" // Is this right 'comparison test with 1/n(n-1)' ? // BTW I am impressed by your answer, thank you

Comment: Yes, the terms are bounded in absolute value by $1/(n-1)n$.

Comment: // THANK YOU VERY MUCH. Have a good day.

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$\frac{(-1)^n}{n+\sin n}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\left(1+\frac{\sin n}{n}\right)^{-1}=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\left(1-\frac{\sin n}{n}+o\left(\frac1n\right)\right)\\=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\sin n}{n^2}+o\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$
so the given series is convergent since it's sum of $3$ convergent series:

- the first by the Leibniz theorem
- the second the third by comparison with a Riemann series.

Comment: Could you give me some supplement for "the 3rd line"? I wonder why '-'(minus)... // thank you

Comment: And you says Riemann series, is this mean [link]http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem

Answer (score 1):

add two consecutive terms together,

$$\frac{1}{n+\sin n}-\frac{1}{n+1+\sin (n+1)}=\frac{\sin (n+1)-\sin n +1}{(n+\sin n)(n+1+\sin (n+1))}$$
Now do a compairison,

$$\frac{|\sin (n+1)-\sin n +1|}{(n+\sin n)(n+1+\sin (n+1))}\leq \frac{3}{(n-1)n}$$

Comment: your idea "add two consecutive terms together".. BUT SUM (-1)^n diverges.. // could you show appropriateness of your idea, please? // THANK YOU

Comment: The terms of $(-1)^n$ do not limit to zero. I am showing that the even partial sums converge, but as they differ, in this case, from the odd partial sums by a quantity that limits to zero, the odd sums also converge and to the same sum.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I am not very sure that my answer is correct or not as these tests are what i learned. Hope this may help you.

Comment: This is wrong as you show divergence of absolute, but not alternating series. This alternating series converges by Leibniz test

Comment: @Alex you are right...So this mean that this series converge conditionally right?

Comment: Yes, check Wikipedia for alternating series test

Answer (score -1):

Easier: see that $-1 \leq \sin n \leq 1 $, hence the bounds on the summand are $\frac{(-1)^n}{n-1}$ and $\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}$ which converge by alternating test (Leibniz test) and hence your original series converges.

Comment: In case of "a_n < c_n < b_n" and SUM a_n = α, SUM b_n = β ,., HOW can I say SUM c_n is converges? // Would you please tell me supplement? // Thank you

Comment: this is called squeeze lemma

Comment: I know squeeze thm for limit and for case an<bn<cn in addition an, cn are converges SAME limit...// BUT this case.. wait a minute, I'll find squeeze thm for series, THANK YOU very much

Comment: both upper and lower series converge, hence $\sum c_n$ converges too

Comment: Also in this case $c_n \sim a_n \sim b_n$ and both $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ converge, hence...

Comment: In your last comment, if SUM a_n is not equal SUM b_n, then we can say SUM c_n converge?

Comment: @Alex Can you provide any reference for the statement "both upper and lower series converge, hence ∑cn converges too".
I doubt that for the case of limit of function its true but in the case of convergence it may be not true.

Comment: @kaka.I think following link may help you★ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549225/proof-of-sandwich-squeeze-theorem-for-series